# Does IIS reset is required after disabling SharePoint Services

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices, iis7

I would like to stop the SharePoint services ( Workflow Timer Service, Web Application service) on Application servers where central admin and search services are hosted.

What are the pre steps and post steps to be taken while performing this activity?

Does an IIS reset required?

Answer (score 3):

Their is no such requirement like u have to reset IIS after stop the services.

We are starting and stopping services all the time without IIS reset.

You have to make sure that you are not stopping the services on your WFE.

In worst case scenrio, when SharePoint cached the endpoints even after stopping service application load balancer service send the requests to that server.

In that case, you have to do IISreset on all servers.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not recommended as it may cause timer jobs to fail when not running the Web Application service on SharePoint 2010 and 2013 (2016 resolves this). In addition, Workflows should only run on the back end (App) servers for performance purposes as they're a batch job and not latency-sensitive.

Comment: The scenario is , my Nintex licenses are applied only on WFE and hence when a user tries to start the workflow on a App server, it fails to start as it is not licensed. As per recommendation of Nintex, when a server is not licensed, Workflow timer service and web application service needs to be stopped. Hence we decided to stop those services on App servers, Will there be any potential impact? What is the best practice to implement on this case?

Comment: That's a bad recommendation on their part and completely falls apart in the 2016 MinRole model. I would push for licenses for App servers. Most SharePoint ISVs will provide you gratis licenses as they're not end user facing servers.

Comment: The environment is SP 2010.

Comment: Yep, and it's still a bad recommendation on their part :-)